# React jest shallowRender getRenderOutput returning null

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I've been studying React, and I tried to make a jest test with the shallowRender but always return null on shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput()

**MyComponent.react.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello World!</div>;
  }
}
```

**__test__/MyComponent.react.js**

```
jest.dontMock('../MyComponent.react.js');

import React from 'react/addons';
import MyComponent from '../MyComponent.react.js';

var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

describe('MyComponent', () => {

  it('test', () => {
    let shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
    shallowRenderer.render(<MyComponent/>);
    let vdom = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();

    console.log(vdom);
    expect(1).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

**npm test**

```
> jest-test@1.0.0 test /home/bruno/Stuffs/jest-test
> jest

Using Jest CLI v0.5.8
 PASS  __tests__/MyComponent.js (0.897s)
null
1 test passed (1 total)
Run time: 1.189s
```

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^5.8.23",
    "babel-jest": "^5.3.0",
    "jest-cli": "^0.5.8",
    "react": "^0.13.3",
    "skin-deep": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "testFileExtensions": [
      "es6",
      "js"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "es6"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The automocking feature does not work with the ES2015 imports so, if you change your `MyComponent` import with `require` statement, your code should be work.

This is the [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/379).

```
jest.dontMock('../MyComponent.react.js');

import React from 'react/addons';
const MyComponent require('../MyComponent.react.js');    // This is the important line!!

var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

describe('MyComponent', () => {

  it('test', () => {
    let shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
    shallowRenderer.render(<MyComponent/>);
    let vdom = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();

    console.log(vdom);
    expect(1).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Tried it out, for me it throws the error "TypeError: Component is not a function"